# Knockout.js mapping JSON objects - only the first array

Tags: json, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

This is the JSON i receive from my Service
It will contain the "first"-Array and a ResponseStatus array.

```
{"Customers":[{"Id":1,"Name":"Thomas","LastName":"Deutsch"},    {"Id":2,"Name":"Julia","LastName":"Baumeistör"}],"ResponseStatus":{}}
```

And this first JSON Array is mapped with the ko.mapping

```
$.getJSON(self.Url, function (data) {
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data.Customers, {}, self.Items);
});
```

it works just fine. But here is the

**Problem**: I can not use "data.Customers" because the server could could also return a "Companies" JSON array on the first position.

**Question**: 
Is a mapping possible, that is only parsing the "FIRST" Array? i am stuck....

Comment: What do you mean, when you say that "server could also return a "Companies" JSON array on the first position"?

Answer (score 0):

This might work for what you're trying to do

```
$.getJSON(self.Url, function (data) {
    $.each(data, function(i, item){

        var customers = getPersonnel(item.Customers);
        var companies = getPersonnel(item.Companies);
        var response = getPersonnel(item.ResponseStatus);

        if(customers != null){
            // Parse JSON here...
        }

        if(companies != null){
            // Parse JSON here...
        }

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define behavior for the mapping plugin.

See http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html (section **"Advanced usage"**)